# Google sheets date in dd-mm-yy format to month in mmm-yyyy format in another column

Tags: date, google-sheets

How do I convert a date in dd-mm-yy format in Google sheets to just month in mmm-yyyy format in another column so that dates within the same month have the same value in month format. 
Currently it's showing different dates as multiple values in my pivot table and I want to show totals for the month or it shows the order wrong because the month is a text value.
[Alpha sort not chronological sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA1Y3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a combination of a formula (to 'convert' all dates to the first of the month):

```
=date(year(A1),month(A1),1)
```

and formatting:

```
mmm-yyyy
```